# XPATH To filter out records with letters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am looking for an XPATH expression that will perform a search to ensure a field does not have a letter in it. For example input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record> 
        <record>
            <number>78A</number>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

I want it too filter out the third result as it has a letter in the tag. So return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

Is that possible to do in a simple XPATH?

So something like `/payload/records/record[reg expression here?]`

**@Cylian**

This is what i mean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
            <time>12pm</time>
            <zome>UK</zome>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
            <time>12pm</time>
            <zome>UK</zome>
        </record> 
        <record>
            <number>78A</number>
            <time>12pm</time>
            <zome>UK</zome>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath (both 1.0 and 2.0) is a query language for XML documents.

As such **an XPath expression only selects sets of nodes (or extracts other data), but cannot alter the structure (like delete a node) of the XML document**.

Therefore, it is not possible to construct an XPath expression that alters the provided XML document to the wanted one.

This task can easily be accomplished with XSLT or XQuery (not so easily):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="record[translate(number, '0123456789', '')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>78A</number>
        </record>
    </records>
</payload>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<payload>
   <records>
      <record>
         <number>123</number>
      </record>
      <record>
         <number>456</number>
      </record>
   </records>
</payload>
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing the opposite so that any field that contains anything BUT a number so a single letter, capitalized, and special characters? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, there is. It would be good to ask this in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete the nodes using an XQuery Update expression, too:

```
for $record in doc('payload.xml')//record
where xs:string(number($record/number)) = 'NaN'
return delete node $record
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this(XPath 2.0):**

```
/payload/records/record[matches(child::*/text(),'[^\p{L}]')]
```

Comment: Quick question, as i am new to XPATH how does this know to look at the number tag specifically?  If say i had two tag sat next to each other `<number/> <time/>` if this was the case how would it pick the number tag? ----- I have added an example at the bottom of my post, as to what i mean.