# XSLT To filter out records with letters

Tags: xslt, filter, records

We have a requirement to filter records with characters in numeric fields and report them separately. I did come across the following question which has been answered -
[XPATH To filter out records with letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431239/xpath-to-filter-out-records-with-letters)

However is there a way to mark these records with a flag or collect them in a variable as we need to report these records as invalid records. If we delete them completely the problem is that we do not have a clue on which of them were invalid.

Please suggest.

Thank You!

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record> 
        <record>
            <number>78A</number>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

XSLT solution from the link above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="record[translate(number, '0123456789', '')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the match, output the original element with whatever "flag" you want (attribute, comment, processing instruction, etc.).

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record[string(number(number))='NaN']">
        <record invalid="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </record>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<payload>
   <records>
      <record>
         <number>123</number>
      </record>
      <record>
         <number>456</number>
      </record>
      <record invalid="true">
         <number>78A</number>
      </record>
   </records>
</payload>
```

You can still use your original match if you'd like.

---

Edit to handle multiple `number` (fields) and identify the specific fields (columns) at the `record` level.

Modified XML input example:

```
<payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number>123</number>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number>456</number>
        </record> 
        <record>
            <number>321</number>
            <number>78A</number>
            <number>654</number>
            <number>abc</number>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>
```

**Updated XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:variable name="invalidCols">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="invalid"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <record>
            <xsl:if test="string($invalidCols)">
                <xsl:attribute name="invalidCols">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($invalidCols)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </record>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number[string(number(.))='NaN']" mode="invalid">
        <xsl:number/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="invalid"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<payload>
   <records>
      <record>
         <number>123</number>
      </record>
      <record>
         <number>456</number>
      </record>
      <record invalidCols="2 4">
         <number>321</number>
         <number>78A</number>
         <number>654</number>
         <number>abc</number>
         <number>123456</number>
      </record>
   </records>
</payload>
```

Comment: Thank You Daniel! Is it possible to flag at the record level instead of field level? Please suggest

Comment: @user3219481 - I updated my answer to flag at the `record` level. The change should've been pretty obvious so if you have questions on what is happening please let me know.

Comment: Thank You Daniel! This really will help me. Is it possible to identify which column has the issue? If I am setting the attribute in a record with multiple fields, It will spot the record but is there a way to identify the combination of record and field. Please suggest.

Comment: @user3219481 - I added another example, but I'm making an assumption that `number` = column. You haven't said what you want exactly, so I'm outputting the "column number" at the `record` level.

Comment: My Bad. The payload would be like <payload>
    <records>
        <record>
            <number1>123</number1>
        </record>
        <record>
            <number1>456</number1>
        </record> 
        <record>
            <number1>321</number1>
            <number2>78A</number2>
            <char1>abc</char1>
            <number3>56B</number3>
        </record> 
    </records>
</payload>

Comment: and is it possible to get the below output  with output <payload>
   <records>
      <record>
         <number1>123</number1>
      </record>
      <record>
         <number1>456</number1>
      </record>
      <record invalid="true" invalidCols="number2, number3">
         <number1>321</number1>
         <number2>78A</number2>
         <char1>abc</char1>
         <number3>56B</number3>
      </record>
   </records>
</payload>

Comment: @user3219481 StackOverflow is provided so you can ask questions and get help in solving problems. It's not there so you can ask other people to do your coding for you, or so that you can avoid taking the trouble to learn the programming language you are using.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am not an expert honestly and not avoiding to learn but I do not know how to do it hence asking. Even not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Thank You Daniel for all the help! My sincere apologies if I asked basic questions but it wasn't intentional. I only asked as I did not know how to do it. Thank You so much!!!